# materil-ui how to push the button very bottom of the paper area

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui. I've put a grid and a button below it on a paper. But I couldn't push the botton to very bottom of the paper. How to push the button very bottom of the paper?

Thanks

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-button-row-buttom-us9on)

Comment: This is just googling css. Look into flexbox or position: absolute to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `display:'flex'` seems to make it:

```
  const MainPaper = styled(Paper)({
    height: "600px",
    margin: "16px",
    padding: "16px",
    display:'flex',
  });
```